# Passing the *class* as function argument

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, module

I've never done this before, and it seems hacky, but I've tested and it does work. Is this considered OK form:

```
from audio.models import audio
from document.models import pdf

def count_object_by_sha1(object_type, sha1):
    return object_type.objects.filter(sha1=sha1).count()

pdf_count = count_object_by_sha1(pdf, 'somesha1valuehere')
audio_count = count_object_by_sha1(audio, 'somesha1valuehere')
```

So basically, I'm passing the class to the function and using it to make a query on one or another django objects. Feels like a hack...but it works and makes my code rather simple.

After running into [the mutable object in function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) issue, I'm a bit skittish about doing weird things with function arguments.

Comment: the linked question has nothing to do with this.  That surprising behavior only applies to the function _definition_, not to passing a mutable argument into a function.  That works as you'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't what you're doing though. You're passing a class, not a module. `pdf` is evidently a Django model class, since it has an `objects` attribute.

Either way is fine, though. Classes and modules are first class objects and it's perfectly OK to pass them around, use them in functions, etc.

Comment: Right. Thanks for that correction and for the reply. I've corrected the question.